# creating a simple linear regression model and get the result 1.367e+02

Tags: r, math, statistics, linear-regression

Im calculating a simple linear regression using the lm() function and get the following output when calling it:

```
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     1.367e+02  4.901e+00   27.90   <2e-16 ***
LCF2010$grosswk 4.855e-01  8.589e-03   56.53   <2e-16 ***
```

Im interested in the Estimate column right now, but cant understand what the values are, considering they have the e character in the middle of them...

Comment: In R , `1.367e+02 = 1.367 * 10 ^2`, so what you have is `136.7` as the estimation for the intercept.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @R18